# how to update a table by joining multiple tables in one step

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to update a table based on sum of the column from another table with no direct relation:

```
X1.POPULATION = SUM(X3.POPULATION)
```

based on two different joins

```
X1.A = X2.A, X2.B = X3.B
```

I can split it into two steps by making temporary table (then 2 queries and 1 temporary table for each update) and then connect them but I hope there is a chance to do it in the same query since I need to apply the same procedure for other tables.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See whether [DSum()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) can give you what you want.

Comment: ^ This will be the only way without a temporary table. Access has a kinda simplistic method here: if a query has any grouping/aggregation anywhere, it will not be updateable, period.